# Encoding duplicate words is not working in the code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I am a learner and i was doing a charachter encoding exercise in codewars
My code is failing in tests for "(" and ")" and random characters

```
def duplicate_encode(word):
    #your code here
    word = word.lower()
    for ch in word:
        if word.count(ch) == 1:
            word = word.replace(ch, "(")
        else:
            word =  word.replace(ch, ")")
    return word
```

can anybody help
The problem statement is as follows :
The goal of this exercise is to convert a string to a new string where each character in the new string is "(" if that character appears only once in the original string, or ")" if that character appears more than once in the original string. Ignore capitalization when determining if a character is a duplicate.

Comment: In what input string does this fail?

Comment: For brackets or a string of random characters

Comment: For example HaO@lknFmcxzI( RHJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example input: `HaO@lknFmcxzI( RHJ`

When your iteration gets as far as the `(`, it will count the number of `(` in the string including some that were not in the original string, because your function puts new `(` into the string.

Also if your function uses `replace(ch, ...)` and `ch` is equal to `(` or `)`, you are altering all the parentheses you have added so far.

A way to avoid that is to not keep altering the string while you're looking at it, but build up a new separate sequence of characters.

```py
def duplicate_encode(word):
    word = word.lower()
    new = []
    for ch in word:
        if word.count(ch) == 1:
            new.append('(')
        else:
            new.append(')')
    return ''.join(new)
```

---

The one liner in your comments:

```
''.join('(' if word.lower().count(ch) == 1 else ')' for ch in word.lower())
```

uses a generator expression. It iterates through the string (transformed to lower case), and generates either `(` or `)` for each one (depending on the count), and then at the end, joins up all the characters to a new string.

Comment: You were pretty close.

Comment: I gave the test on code wars but it failed for 19 tests one of them was:

Comment: lPFwRan)wbuHJxb!vJTPdl e

Comment: I am not much accustomed to one liners but this was some solution i found on git hub
If you could explain it to me maybe
`return ''.join('(' if word.lower().count(ch) == 1 else ')' for ch in word.lower())`

Comment: I've revised my answer and added a description of your one-liner.